# Plugin error when adding Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile project to android gradle multiproject build

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I have two projects, **android library** (which is supposed to be used in other projects) and **Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile project** which holds some common code to be shared between android and iOS versions of the library. I understand that KMM project should contain code for both android and iOS versions inside, rather than having separate KMM and android/iOS projects, but since these projects already exist and are extensive, it'd be difficult to merge them into single KMM project so instead I've chosen to include code from KMM shared module into android library build.

project directory structure:

```
AndroidLibrary  <--- android library
|- kmmLibrary   <--- KMM project
  |- shared
    |- build.gradle
  |- build.gradle
  |- settings.gradle
|- lib          <---- android library module
  |- build.gradle
|- build.gradle
|- settings.gradle
```

I've decided that instead of building shared project separately and declaring it as regular dependency in library build, available by dependency repository (so e.g. `implementation "example.com:mylib:1.0"` in `AndroidLibrary/lib/build.gradle`), it's better to find a way to "join" shared module into library build since both are build by gradle anyway. This would ease everyday development process (avoid need to publish shared artifacts to maven local each time shared code is changed in order to use changed code in library project and any project that declares the library as dependency).

I've tried to simply include shared into library build:

*AndroidLibrary/settings.gradle*

```
include ':kmmLibrary:shared'
```

but on gradle sync in AS (or running `./gradlew` inside `AndroidLibrary` directory) I get an error:

```
Build file '/pathtotheproject/AndroidLibrary/kmmLibrary/build.gradle.kts' line: 1

Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform', version: '1.8.21', apply: false]

> The request for this plugin could not be satisfied because the plugin is already on the classpath with an unknown version, so compatibility cannot be checked.
```

Such error is surprising as the only places where multiplatform plugin is resolved or applied is KMM project, which builds fine on its own (running `./gradlew` inside `AndroidLibrary/kmmLibrary` dir finishes with success, error happens only when building AndroidLibrary)

All places where multiplatfom plugin is used:

*AndroidLibrary/kmmLibrary/build.gradle.kts*

```
plugins {
    //trick: for the same plugin versions in all sub-modules
    id("com.android.library").version("8.0.2").apply(false)
    kotlin("multiplatform").version("1.8.21").apply(false)
}
...
```

*AndroidLibrary/kmmLibrary/shared/build.gradle.kts*

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
}
...
```

I've uploaded sample code [here](https://bitbucket.org/PiotrSmietanaPriv/kmm-library-gradle-sample-code). Run `./gradlew` in main directory to reproduce the error.

---

I've managed to make it work with gradle composite build (using `includeBuild 'kmmLibrary:shared'`) but I'd prefer to keep it as multiproject build (so using regular `include ':kmmLibrary:shared'`) due to way build artifacts are handled. Using includeBuild won't allow me to declare project dependency on shared module (`api project(":kmmLibrary:shared")`) which would include classes from shared module in build artifact of AndroidLibrary, which is later intended to itself become a dependency to a 3rd project. Using `includeBuild` would require `kmmLib/shared` module to be separately published to maven so 3rd project could access it's classes (as transient dependency of AndroidLibrary). I'd like to avoid that so only library needs to be published for changes to propagate to any project having library as dependency.